# Undefined variable $tweet in home.blade.php view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following a tutorial from [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/57?autoplay=true) and I'm making a clone of Twitter. I've got a home.blade.php and a HomeController.php file. In the HomeController I've got a function called index, which calls the home view. He also sends a variable called "tweets".

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home', [
        'tweets' => App\Tweet::all()
    ]);
}
```

In the home.blade.php file I use blade to show the variable, but I get this error: `Undefined variable: tweet (View: C:\wamp64\www\laravel\tweety\resources\views\home.blade.php)`

Here's my home.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('timeline')
<article>
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="meta">
            <span class="author">
                {{ $tweet->user->name }}
            </span>
            <span class="time">
                &bullet; 10m
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            {{ $tweet->body }}
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
@endsection
```

I've searched on the internet to a solution, but couldn't find one. If you need more information, please tell me.

Thank you!
Jeroen van Rensen

Comment: You are returning `tweets` not `tweet`. I think you'll have to loop over `$tweets` to print each tweet attributes. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops

Comment: Hello porloscerros, I'm running a loop over `$tweets`, so that isn't the problem. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tweets` is an array. You need foreach loop.
It loops over the array, and each value for the current array element is assigned to `$tweet`

Try this :

```
@extends('layout')
@section('timeline')
@foreach($tweets as $tweet)
<article>
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="meta">
            <span class="author">
                {{ $tweet->user->name }}
            </span>
            <span class="time">
                &bullet; 10m
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            {{ $tweet->body }}
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Now he does work. But isn't there an option so I can keep the article in the home.blade.php file? That looks a little bit cleaner